# String with character repetition

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me on this one? Given a string, I have to return a string in which each character (case-sensitive) is repeated once.

```
doubleChar("String") ==> "SSttrriinngg"

doubleChar("Hello World") ==> "HHeelllloo  WWoorrlldd"

doubleChar("1234!_ ") ==> "11223344!!__  "


function doubleChar(str) {

}
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far and where you are having a specific problem

Comment: Using `.replace()` you can grab every character using the regex `/./g` and then replace it with its "doubled" version: `str.replace(/./g, c => c+c);`

Comment: @NickParsons I didn't even know it's possible to loop within the `.replace` method! So cool!

Comment: @Ludolfyn its handy for strings since they're immutable. Sort of acts as a `.map()` but for strings

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method for this like:

```js
function doubleChar(str) {
  return [...str].map(s => s.repeat(2)).join('')
}

console.log(doubleChar("String"))
console.log(doubleChar("Hello World"))
console.log(doubleChar("1234!_ "))
```

Comment: I see, thanks. But what does the s stand for?

Comment: `s` is just a variable name for the currentValue inside `[...str]` array. So, if you pass `String`, then inside `.map()` method `s` will first "S", then "t", "r" and so on..

Comment: Very nice! @BenjaminH.Dean the s is the iterator—the count for every array item/letter.

Comment: you could also use `Array.from(str, s => s.repeat(2)).join('')` which would remove the need for the temporary array and perform the character mappings and iteration at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const str = 'hello'
let arr = str.split('')
const double = arr.map(i => i += i).join('')

console.log(double)
```